# Drag and drop in SplitLayoutPanel not working properly

Tags: gwt, gwtquery, gquery

I'm trying to drag row from cell table, to my other widget. To do this i created `DragAndDropCellTable` and `DroppableWidget`. While they were in same container it was working fine. But since i put them to SplitLayoutPanel, it is not working properly. I still got drop event, but helper is not visible. I tried to set z-index on helper but this didn't help.

Is any one has idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to set the option `appendTo` to `"body"` ? The cause is certainly because the overflow css property of the split panel is set to hidden hidden

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, but I don't get your answer completely.
I guess you mean that the helper is hidden when it leaves the panel cause of the overflow hidden. Am I right so far?
But i don't get how to append. How can I append the helper to the rootPanel?
Or am I on the wrong track with this?

---

Ok I got it.
I don't have to append the helper but the DraggableOptions to `"body"`

```
draggableOptions.setAppendTo("body");
```

https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DraggablePluginGettingStarted#DraggableOptions_Object

Thanks